How to extract frames from a video using ffmpeg?
Basically I want to extract all frames from the video where the images will be resized to be 720p. All of this I know how to do. But for testing I want to extract every Nth frame. So every 30th image from a 30FPS video or every 10th image, etc. How can I do that?
Also the extracted image filenames should correspond to the frame numbers so not sure if the first frame is 0 or 1?

This is actually pretty trivial:
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -r 1 -an -c:v mjpeg 'test%03d.jpeg'

This will extract 1 frame per second. Now we want to adjust the numbers to be frame numbers rather than just a sequence, we know that they all have leading zeros, and are 3 digits long (see %03d). Therefore we can do:
for f in test*.jpeg; do num=${f:4:3}; let newnum=$((10#$num))*60; newname="${f/$num/$newnum}"; mv $f $newname;  done

This assumes that the original frame rate was 60, we just multiply every number by that value. If your case has a different original frame rate, change that.
